# How to avoid IIS reset the application pool in the server

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6

Most of the time when a user enter to the site, it take a lot of time to load the first time to the page, after the page works well for user and  other users in other networks. 
I created a cache that is store in an application variable to reduces the access to the data base and increase the performance but It is reset when the application pool is restart.
I can´t have access to the IIS application pool on the server because it a server that share different applications. How can I do to change the time that the application pool is reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't (I'm sure) because this is controlled by IIS itself not code. What can you do is prime the cache on application start though